# How to update a value in a mongoose document?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am trying to modify a piece of code written by another person.

I need to update a mongodb document rather than removing it.

Here is the code :

```
const docs = await docsModel.find({});

for (const doc of docs) {
  doc.remove();
}
```

I need to update rather than remove. I've tried this :

```
const docs = await docsModel.find({});

for (const doc of docs) {
  doc.updateOne({field_I_want_to_update : "new_value"});
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on situation.

If you want to update multiple document with the **same** value, then better would be:

```
doc.updateMany(<filter>, { $set: { field_I_want_to_update : "new_value" } });
```

Where: `<filter>` would be something like: `{ _id: <validId> }` or `{ _id: { $in: [<array_of_ids>] } }`

---

If you want to update multiple documents with **dynamic** values, then this would work:

```
const docs = await docsModel.find({});

docs.forEach(function(doc) {
  await docsModel.updateOne({ _id: doc._id }, { $set: { field_I_want_to_update: "new_dynamic_value" } });
});
```

Comparing to your case, you're missing `<filter>` as the first parameter, and in second you need to start with `$set: { <field>: <value> }` rather with `{ <field>: <value> }`

Answer (score 1):

You can use mongoose `updateMany` function which takes in a filter and an object of keys and values to update. wrap the object in a `$set` property. In theory, you could for-loop and use `findByIdAndUpdate` but that's a resource hog.
So something like

```js
await docsModel.updateMany({}, {$set: { /*insert field name*/: /*insert field value*/ } });
```